# How can a server rendered page determine if cookies are expired?

Tags: authentication, cookies, server, svelte

I have a sveltekit app and in my `layout.server.ts` file, which runs on the server, I make a request to another endpoint to check if the user is authenticated. I'm doing this server side because I don't want to flash any data.

A cookie is used for session management but every time the cookie expires I get an error back from the other endpoint telling me that the cookie has expired.

The browser determines if a cookie has expired and if so removes it before making a request, but what if that request happens serverside?

How can I tell my server to remove the cookie if it has expired like the browser does by default before it makes a request to another endpoint?

Comment: Where do you get the cookie from?

Comment: The cookie comes from the same server as the request goes to.

Comment: So your server makes an auth request to an external service and gets a cookie in response. That response presumably uses a set-cookie header? You can read the value in the [set-cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#permanent_cookie) header and extract the expiration time. Store it together with your cookie and check it before making the request.

Comment: Yes correct. should I store the cookie expiration date in db?

Comment: That is an option.
If that cookie is user specific you could store it in the user's cookies and concat it with the timestamp. When using it you could extract the timestamp from the value, parse, check and decide what to do.